# Installing i3wm on Manjaro with KDE

Tags: kde, i3, manjaro

I recently installed the Manjaro i3wm edition and I actually quite liked it. 
But there were some things that simply didn't work out of the box (like multi-monitor setup etc.) and I simply dind't want to have to configure them to get basic functionallity.

Now I am back to Manjaro with KDE and everythings works fine (it also feels better because it is an "official flagship Manjaro").

But I kinda miss i3 so I am thinking about installing i3 in my Manjaro with KDE so I will be able to switch between them (then it doesn't matter if i3 has no multi-monitor support out of the box).

Are there things I need to know before installing i3? Are there programs that won't work right with it that are installed with Manjaro KDE? Do I need to install additional software to get i3 to work or will it fetch everything it needs?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

To share or preview workspace in other monitor from i3 you need to configure it manually

using `xrandr` command

see the complete list in i3 docs

http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html

where 7th one explain how to display workspace in other monitors

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to use this page instaid.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3 Most everything in the arch wiki applies to Manjaro as well.  Have fun.   No programs should rely on other things and it should just pull itself.  There may be other packages but everything’s on that page.