# manjaro kde plasma and i3wm

Tags: kde, manjaro, window-manager, i3, kwin

I really like Manjaro Plasma flavour and how it works out of the box, but at the same time I'd like to have the features of a i3wm to improve usability and productivity.

Is it possible to get rid of KWin and use i3wm on top of KDE Plasma?

I tried a lot. The most promising tutorial I found was this one: https://github.com/heckelson/i3-and-kde-plasma but with no results.

Other resources I've used:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227301
- https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/elzfhs/hey_everyone_i_wrote_a_little_guide_on_how_to_use/
- https://janyie.qc.to/kde-plasma-i3wm-arch-plasma-5-25-update/
- [Installing i3wm on Manjaro with KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339453/installing-i3wm-on-manjaro-with-kde)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a systemd user unit to start your preferred WM and mask the KWin service. The details on how to do this can be found in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE#Use_a_different_window_manager).